# asp.net using jquery and javascript to determine middle part of ID of textbox that matches button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex, webforms

I have a button in which it is legacy app in asp.net webforms and so these generated id's are what I have to work with:

```
<input type="button" onclick="setDateTimeOn(this);" name="GridView1:_ctl2:AddButton0" value="On" id="GridView1__ctl2_AddButton0" class="btn-blue">


<input name="GridView1:_ctl2:txtStormTimeOn" type="text" id="GridView1__ctl2_txtStormTimeOn">
```

I have a function that I call

```
function setDateTimeOn(x){

    //alert(x.id);   
    console.log(x.id);
    //$('#x.id').val(

    //NEED TO SET textbox to date and time in this format --> 09-11-2015 10:03

}
```

I need to use jquery or javascript to find the "ctl2" THUS really parsing to find the characters BEFORE "_ctl2_AddButton0" and AFTER "GridView1__"

There is some code that I used in the past which jquery with regex in which I would  use   "^" and with part of the name , but in this case I know that the format is always

```
 GridView1__VALUEIWANT_txtStormTimeOn
```

then I know how to populate my textbox with that value   ( there are many rows all gridview pre-generated with asp.net web forms and I can't be changing it in this application.

**Edit/Update**

So far this is closer

```
function setDateTimeOn(x){


console.log(x.id);   // shows GridView1__ctl2_AddButton0


var re = /__(.+)_/; 
// your control name was used an as example:
//var str = 'GridView1__ctl2_AddButton0';

var str = x.id;
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// m[0] == 'ctl2'

    console.log(m[0]);  // shows __ctl2_
```

}

**EDIT 2:**

```
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="button" name="GridView1:_ctl2:AddButton0" value="On" id="GridView1__ctl2_AddButton0" class="btn-blue">
       </td>
        <td style="width:150px;">
        <input name="GridView1:_ctl2:txtStormTimeOn" type="text" value="asdfasdf" id="GridView1__ctl2_txtStormTimeOn">
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are passing the control to the function as a parameter. Can you not just use that variable? Ex: `x.val("9/11/2015");`

Comment: If you have access to the serverside code, you could do the following. In ASP.NET you can set the following property for your button. ClientIdMode="static" and then you can name the ID's yourself on the serverside and they will show as such on the client side.

Comment: @gotmilk13531    x = the button control  ,  I need to set the textbox control

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder    I want a generic function in which even if I had clientidmode of static ,  for example --> my13button   needs to be looked at in order to then on client side with the same row say with name   my13textbox

Comment: Name your text box textbox14 or textboxXX. And then in JavaScript .replace('text box','')

Comment: please add more markup

Comment: @naveen   I think that there is plenty of markup .    I can remove the __ and _  with    var z = m[0].replace('__', '');
        var z = z.replace('_', '');

Comment: you are approaching the problem in the wrong way. I assume that both the button and textbox reside in the same row. I was asking the markup of that tr. Also please explain this sentence *I need to use jquery or javascript to find the "ctl2" THUS really parsing to find the characters BEFORE "_ctl2_AddButton0" and AFTER "GridView1__"*

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  thx  hang on

Comment: are they adjacent `td`s? the exact markup is very important.

Comment: Yes they are adjacent tds  ( I understand why you are asking ,  I did remove other tds before and after this html,   but YES , they are adjacent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function setDateTimeOn(elm) {
    var formattedDate = GetCurrentDateTime(); //get formatted date
    $(elm) //clicked button
        .parent("td") // container td
        .next() // next td
        .find("input") // find child input
        .val(formattedDate); //set date
}
function GetCurrentDateTime() {
    var now = new Date(),
        hours = now.getHours(),
        ampm = hours < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
    hours = (hours % 12 ) || 12;
    return (now.getMonth() + 1) + "-" 
        + now.getDate() + "-" 
        + now.getFullYear() + " " 
        + hours + ":" 
        + pad(now.getMinutes()) + " "
        + ampm;
}
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}
```

No need to omit `onclick="setDateTimeOn(this);"`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/p60at2x5/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following code:

```
var re = /__(.+)_/; 
// your control name was used an as example:
var str = 'GridView1__ctl2_AddButton0';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // m[0] == 'ctl2'
}
```

Comment: m[0] = __ctl2_     ,  close but I want  ctl2  not the underscores before and after

Comment: actually it shows   > __ctl2_    underscore is not coming through at end in comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard to find ID's that contain a certain string.

```
$('[id*="ctl2"]')
```

You might need to narrow down the target if there are other elements on the page that have the search string in their ID.